# leaflet, I would like to type an address and then it would be marked on the map

Tags: leaflet

I'm working with leaflet for the first time, someone would have an example with a label, I would like to type an address and then it would be marked on the map.
Thanks

Comment: Try https://github.com/perliedman/leaflet-control-geocoder

Comment: Just be aware of the words "reverse geocoding".